# Retrieving big amount of rows one by one using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to retrieve big amount of rows from MySQL database and i can not load it all to variable, because it would be too big. Is there a way to load rows pdo like using eloquent queries?

```php
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['name']."<br />\n";
}
```

I would like to do same using eloquent query builder

Comment: you may use chunk for eloquent : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Have you considering pagination: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunking results using `chunk()` is your best option.

```
DB::table('users')->chunk(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {

        // process data

        return false; // break if needed
    }
});
```

The same can be achieved using Eloquent.

```
User::chunk(100, function ($users) {
    ...
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results)